# Fuelphp image resize disable upscaling

Tags: php, image, fuelphp

I'm resizing images uploaded by my users like this:

```
$resized_image = Image::load($public_asset_path_img . DS . $file_name, false, $saved_image[0]['extension']);
$resized_image->resize('1024,1024');
$resized_image->save($public_asset_path_img . DS . "resized_" . $file_name);
```

Now the issue that I'm having is that I only want the image to be resized if it's larger than 1024px wide, I don't want Fuelphp to upscale the image (and lose quality) if it's smaller than 1024px wide.

Is there some kind of config I can disable to make sure upscaling isn't happening from the Fuel::Image class?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [getimagesize](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php) to get image height or width or both.

```
list($width, $height) = getimagesize($filename);
```

Comment: I was hoping there would be an easier way to achieve this, I'll try it out!

Comment: Not really working, I'm looking for a method that can be used with the \Fuel \Core\Image_Gd class

Comment: There is a `sizes` method in the image object: http://fuelphp.com/docs/classes/image.html#/method_sizes

Comment: Currently upscale prevention is not possible. I think the image class will be deprecated in v2 and other implementations, like https://packagist.org/packages/imagine/imagine or https://packagist.org/packages/intervention/image will be recommended.

Comment: @mark.sagikazar I tried the sizes method but I couldn't quite get it to return any values at all